# Ordering date (dd-mm-yyyy) in SQL using Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that returns the *date*,*value*, and *category*:

```
SELECT Date, Value, Category FROM MyTable
```

**Outputs:**

```
18-Dec-2011 ||  6 || Toys   
01-Apr-2012 || -4 || Dog Collars
31-May-2012 ||  4 || Cat
17-Dec-2011 ||  3 || Health & Hygiene    
12-Dec-2011 ||  3 || Travel & Training
```

When I add `Order By Date ASC` it puts the date in ascending order based on the ***date*** not the year.

I want it to look like this:

```
12-Dec-2011 ||  3 || Travel & Training 
17-Dec-2011 ||  3 || Health & Hygiene
18-Dec-2011 ||  6 || Toys
01-Apr-2012 || -4 || Dog
31-May-2012 ||  4 || Cat
```

**Note:** `Date` is of type `string`. I am using [[image]google-bigquery](/questions/tagged/google-bigquery).

How can I get the year in ascending order first, followed by the month, and then date?

Comment: `Date is of type string`. There's your problem. Fix that. There's a reason for the existance of a DateTime type ;-) If you can't fix it because the database is set in stone for some reason you might want to cast it as DateTime.

Comment: @RobIII - ok, i will try converting and see how it goes.

Comment: @Madhivanan - i am using google-bigquery

Comment: Do ***not*** store dates as strings, store them as `DATE`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Unfortunately when the CSV fille is uploaded on Google-BigQuery Valid types are "string", "integer", "float", and "boolean". If the type is omitted, it is assumed to be "string". So i am unable to do much there.

Since I am using JavaScript on the client side, i have a different solution to solve it. Thanks alot anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: as FH below says, "BigQuery has a Timestamp type now: developers.google.com/bigquery/timestamp"

<strike>BigQuery does not currently have a Date or DateTime datatype.</strike> You could also store your datestamps in BigQuery as integers in [POSIX (UNIX epoch) date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), and can convert them to human readable time using the [FORMAT_UTC_USEC function](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#timestampfunctions).

An alternative would be to store datestamps as strings in the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.uuuuuu` format, convert them in your ordered query using the  PARSE_UTC_USEC() function.

Comment: 2013 update: BigQuery has a Timestamp type now: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Convert the date to a date format ISO 9000 style yyyy-mm-dd then order it (perhaps in a new separate column if you want to keep the other date format for rendering purposes).

Comment: I disagree: For "rendering purposes" one should use BigQuery date formatting functions such as STRFTIME_UTC_USEC and FORMAT_UTC_USEC. Why waste space on re-formatted date strings, especially when data sizes get massive?

Comment: I did say perhaps and put it in brackets as if to suggest whimsical ponderings...

Comment: I agree: For new users (like me!) it is better to start with standard date format instead of using unix timestamps.

Answer (score -3):

SQL Server, MySQL

```
Order By CAST(Date AS DATETIME) ASC
```

ORACLE

```
Order By TO_DATE(Date,'DD-Mon-YYYY') ASC
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Google BigQuery - it uses a SQL-like language, but not standard SQL

Comment: Whilst the answer does not mention BigQuery directly, I have just added the following code inspired by this answer to my BQ query and it works just fine.
`ORDER BY field ASC` It's also the only answer to actually answer the question which is how to **order**.