# Datetime in Apps Script

Tags: sql, datetime, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

var dataInicial = '2012-11-01 00:00:00';

var dataFinal = '2012-11-02 22:00:00';

var strOrders = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT orders_id, date_purchased FROM `zen_orders` WHERE `orders_status` IN (3, 48, 49, 53) AND `last_modified` BETWEEN ' + dataInicial + ' AND ' + dataFinal);

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND 2012-11-02 22:00:00' at line 1 (linha 12)

This query work on PHP :(

Comment: Does it work if you use dates explicitly instead of using the variable?  e.g. `last_modified BETWEEN  '2012-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-02 22:00:00'`

Comment: Looks like your RDMS (which one?) doesn't like the space between the date and the time. Try wrapping these parts in quotes.

Comment: @RafaelGadottiBachovas apart from Dale's tip, there could also be an issue with the inverted commas. Is this the first time you are running into this issue with this kind of a query? I noticed some of the Wordpress DB's & [Adobe having similar issues.](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/849037)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For e.g. MS ACCESS SQL dates have `#` to wrap them. The correct character to use when including a literal date value is the pound character (#). [Reference MS Access](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-working-with-dates-in-microsoft-access/6135056). It really matters when you do date calculations. Perhaps there are certain characters/prefixes you may need to use for SQL within Google Script. So it's great if could check out on a article that talks about using dates/ parameterized dates/ building the sql string for Google Script..

To narrow down the issue give this a try:

```
var strOrders = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT orders_id, date_purchased 
FROM zen_orders WHERE orders_status IN (3, 48, 49, 53) 
AND last_modified BETWEEN last_modified - Interval 7 day AND Now());
```

If this is working in your script well, then surely it's something to do with the way you parse the date. The format.

Assuming you are using **GOOGLE BigQuery**, just know that BigQuery does not currently have a `Date` or `DateTime` datatype. You should store your datestamps in BigQuery as integers in `POSIX (UNIX epoch)` date format, and can convert them to human readable time using the `FORMAT_UTC_USEC` function.

An alternative would be to store datestamps as strings in the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.uuuuuu` format, convert them in your ordered query using the `PARSE_UTC_USEC()` function.

- [Reference BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609524/ordering-date-11-jan-2012-in-sql-using-google-bigquery)